# Pagination with Nuxt UI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, nuxt.js, vue-component

I'm trying to implement the pagination component from Nuxt UI, but I am unable to make it work..

I tried to read the docs and youtube, but nothing to be found. I don't understand how to bind my data to the component.

```
<template>
        <div>
            <ul class="p-5">
            <li v-for="creator in creators" class="mb-5">
                <nuxt-link
                :key="creator.id"
                :to="`/creator/${creator.slug}`">
                <div class="creatorCard" :style="{ background: `url(${creator.banner}) center center no-repeat`, backgroundSize: `100% auto` }">
                    <div class="glassEffect">
                        <div class="text pl-5 items-end h-1 pb-2">
                            <p class="font-bold">{{ creator.label }}</p>
                            <p class="italic">{{ creator.ig }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nuxt-link>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="pb-4">
        <UPagination :ui="{ wrapper: 'justify-center'}" v-model="page" :page-count="7" :total="creators.length" />
    </div>
</div>
</template>


<script setup lang="ts">
const page = ref(1);

const creators = useCreators();

useHead({
  title: 'Creators',
})
</script>
```

Comment: UPagination does not actually paginate your data for you, you have to slice the data using the `page` and page-count values yourself, this will create the effect of "syncing" the pagination component with your visible data.  See the example code for [pagination with Nuxt Table](https://ui.nuxt.com/dev/data/table#paginable). It uses a computed property to determine how to slice the visible rows.

Comment: wow it actually worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Bind data meta on the component props and use `@click` event on `<UPagination>` and update your data using `v-model` which reads the value from the component and pass it to the GET method on data fetch request.

Here is a very basic implementation:

```html
<UPagination 
  :ui="{ wrapper: 'justify-center'}" 
  v-model="page" 
  :page-count="meta.per_page" 
  :total="meta.total"
  @click="update"
/>
```

```
const page = ref(1);
const creators = useCreators(page.value);
        
function update(){
  const creators = useCreators(page.value);
}
```